# Handmade desktop icon duplicates when add it to Favorites and launch application

Tags: gnome, python, icons, dock, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda and created icon with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51691898/how-to-create-a-desktop-entry-for-anaconda-on-ubuntu-17-10) manual on my Ubuntu 23.04.

Here is my icon code.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Anaconda-Navigator
GenericName=Anaconda
Comment=Scientific Python Development Environment - Python3
Exec=/home/mika/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator
Categories=Development;Science;IDE;Qt;Education;
Icon=/home/mika/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/icons/Icon1024.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-python;
```

Everything works, except a number of icons in the HotBar.

If I add the application from Dock to favorites, it will appear, but after launching the application - another icon appears, instead of highlighting the icon, which was actually launched.

Here is the example. Favorite icon - green circle. New appeared icon - white square, with green circle. This second icon - is normal anaconda's icon style, when I launch it manually, from terminal.

[image: example]

I use custom HotBar, but I have the same icon behavior even with the default bar

[image: example]

How can I fix it and achieve single highlighted icon behavior?

Comment: The application is `/home/mika/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator`  and not your icon and shortcut ... Although you linked them but they are not actually linked ... Any GUI  window will have its icon on the bar, try e.g. `zenity --info` ... Your best bet is to pin the other icon to the bar and use it as a launcher instead of your shortcut ... You might be able to change its icon though if you dig a little bit AFAIK.